# Node-red not detecting null value

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am trying to build a flow, that reads sensor data and transfers by CANBUS. Sometimes, `null` data is coming what I mean is `tempInt` or `ldrInt` could be null.

```
   var msg2 = {
   payload:
       {
           "$class": "org.acme.testnetwork.UpdateSensorData",
           "sampDevice": "houseMehmet",
           "newTempVal": tempInt,
           "newLightVal": ldrInt,
           "timeStamp": Date().toString()
       }
   };
```

Although I can access `msg.payload.newLightVal` and set it to any value, in the case that its value is null, the control statement such below fails.

```
if(msg.payload.newLightVal===null){
    msg.payload.newLightVal = -1 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `tempInt`  and  `ldrInt` are `null` and not `undefined` .
I think they may be `undefined` in which case replace `===` with `==` in the if statement i.e

```
if(msg.payload.newLightVal==null)
```

Edit : Since the msg.payload.newLightVal is NaN , this should be the if clause

```
 if(msg.payload.newLightVal==null || isNaN(msg.payload.newLightVal))
```

Comment: I assumed you are right and write a piece like below 
if(msg.payload.newLightVal==null || msg.payload.newLightVal===null){
            msg.payload.newLightVal=-1;
        }

Still it is not working

Comment: The part after the || is not necessary anyways  .
 please do an else for the if condition  and console the msg.payload  and let me know  
if(msg.payload.newLightVal==null){
    msg.payload.newLightVal = -1 ;
}else{ 
console.log(msg.payload) ;
}

Comment: '$class': 'org.acme.testnetwork.UpdateSensorData',
  sampDevice: 'houseMehmet',
  newTempVal: 23.92,
  newLightVal: NaN,
  timeStamp: 'Fri Nov 03 2017 14:58:55 GMT+0300 (+03)' }